# square-free parts of values of polynomials

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, analytic-number-theory

Given a polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ of degree $d$, consider the following three sets:

$$N_1(x) = \#\{k \leq x: f(k) \text{ is square-free}\}$$
$$N_2(x) = \#\{n \leq x: n = f(k) \text{ is square-free}\}$$
$$N_3(x) = \#\{n \leq x: n \text{ is the square-free part of $f(k)$}\}$$

Generally, we should have that $N_1(x) \sim c x$ (not proven for large degrees, assumes that $f$ satisfies the necessary congruence conditions).  Then $N_2(x) \sim c' x^{1/d}$.  What do we know about the growth of $N_3(x)$? Do we get significantly more values by considering square-free parts and not just square-free values?

Any references for this would be appreciated.

Edit: Changed from big-O notation to make order of growth more precise.

Comment: In the third part, do you consider $k\leq x$ or all $k$?

Comment: For all $\epsilon$, for almost all $x$, the squarefree part of $x$ is greater than $x^{1-\epsilon}$. I think this implies that you do not get an exponential improvement, at least as the only reasonable conjecture.

Comment: Thanks Will! Yes, for the third, I'm considering all $k$.  What you wrote makes a lot of sense... there aren't many integers divisible by large squares, and so allowing square-free parts shouldn't help all that much.

Comment: You probably should write $N_1(x) = \Omega(x)$ or $N_1(x) \gg x$, and similarly for $N_2(x)$; the notation $O(x)$ indicates only an upper bound.

Comment: The case $N_1(x) \gg x$ is only expected to be true if $f$  has no fixed square divisor, and can only be proved for $\deg(f) \leq 3$, and for most cases of $\deg(f) = 4$ except for certain classes of Galois groups. I am not aware of any progress on the second problem. The third should be a minor exponential adjustment from the third. However, estimates for $N_1(x)$ is known given the $abc$-conjecture; this is due to Granville.

Comment: @WillSawin do you have a reference for the result you mentioned?

Comment: @bean No, but it's a quick argument using either sieves or Euler products, I think.